# Repopulate an SQL filled HTML table based on select option

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net, vb.net, select

I'm basically trying to merge two pieces of existing code.

- First part is a an SQL populated select box. Gets a list of all of the people underneath the manager that is logged in and uses this list to populate the select options.
- Second part is a table populated by SQL which brings back a new row with each instance of a booked off holiday period.

As it is I just have a table that shows my own holiday and a select box with all of my managers

How would I go about joining the two so when I change the selected item, it repopulates the table?

I have a variable 
`strEmployee = Request.Form("selectUN")` but I have no idea where to put it and how to make the table repopulate.

Thanks in advance!

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="/incs/KAMBE_SQL.asp" -->
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="/incs/KAMHR_SQL.asp" -->
<%
'Query O/S for User and etc
Dim strUser

    strUser = mid(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),12)

Dim msqlSQL, objRSSQL, strManager, strFullname, strEmailAddress,strEmployee, strEntitlement, cnum, HolidayRows, strNoRecords, TeamMemberRows, strYourTeam
    strEmployee = Request.Form("selectUN")

'USER SELECTION ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Creates variable containing logged in users full name--------------------
    msqlSQL = "SELECT KAM_STAFF.Fullname " & _
    "FROM KAM_STAFF " & _
    "WHERE (((KAM_STAFF.Username)='" & strUser & "'))"
    Set objRSSQL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRSSQL.Open msqlSQL, objConnSQL

    If Not objRSSQL.EOF Then
      strFullname = objRSSQL.Fields("FullName")
    End If

    objRSSQL.Close
    Set objRSSQL = Nothing
    'Creates variable containing logged in users full name--------------------

    'collects all users where line manager = full name of logged in user------
    msqlSQL = "SELECT kam_staff.fullname, kam_staff.username, kam_staff.ManagerCopy " & _
    "FROM KAM_STAFF " & _
    "WHERE (((KAM_STAFF.Username) Is Not Null) AND ((KAM_STAFF.[Line Manager])='" & strFullname & "')) " & _
    "ORDER BY KAM_STAFF.FullName"
    Set objRSSQL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRSSQL.Open msqlSQL, objConnSQL

    If Not objRSSQL.EOF Then
        strFullname = objRSSQL.Fields("FullName")
        TeamMemberRows = objRSSQL.GetRows
    End If

    objRSSQL.Close
    Set objRSSQL = Nothing
    'collects all users where line manager = full name of logged in user------
'USER SELECTION ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'HOLIDAY TABLE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'total holiday entitlement from personnel table----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    msqlSQL = "SELECT Personnel.Holiday_Entitlement " & _
    "FROM Personnel " & _
    "WHERE (((Personnel.Username)='" & strEmployee & "'))"
    Set objRSSQL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRSSQL.Open msqlSQL, objConnHRSQL

    If Not objRSSQL.EOF Then
      strEntitlement = objRSSQL.Fields("Holiday_Entitlement")
    End If

    objRSSQL.Close
    Set objRSSQL = Nothing
    'strEntitlement ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'select fields for holiday section----------------------------------------------------------
    msqlSQL = "SELECT HR_Forms.HR_Form_ID, HR_Forms.Hol_LastWorkingDate, HR_Forms.Hol_FirstWorkingDate, HR_Forms.Hol_NoOfDaysOff, HR_Forms.ManagersSignature, HR_Forms.Hol_SSUpdatedBy, HR_Forms.Hol_LastWorkingDateHalf, HR_Forms.Hol_FirstWorkingDateHalf, HR_Forms.Declined " & _
    "FROM HR_Forms LEFT JOIN Personnel ON HR_Forms.ClaimsHandlerUN = Personnel.Username " & _
    "WHERE (((HR_Forms.Type)='HOL') AND ((HR_Forms.ClaimsHandlerUN)='" & strEmployee & "') AND (DatePart(yyyy, Hol_LastWorkingDate)=" & DatePart("yyyy", Date()) & ") AND ((Personnel.Employment_Status)<>'Left')) " & _
    "ORDER BY HR_Forms.Hol_LastWorkingDate"
    Set objRSSQL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRSSQL.Open msqlSQL, objConnHRSQL

    If Not objRSSQL.EOF Then
      strNoRecords = 0
      HolidayRows = objRSSQL.GetRows
    Else
      strNoRecords = 1
    End If

    objRSSQL.Close
    Set objRSSQL = Nothing
    objConnHRSQL.Close
    Set objConnHRSQL = Nothing
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'HOLIDAY TABLE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HR Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #666666;}
a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #5677B4;}
a:link {text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;color: #5677B4;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: #000000;}
a:active {text-decoration: none;color: #000000;}
.style1 {font-size:16px; color:#5677B4; font-weight:bold}
.style2 {color:#000000}
.style3 {font-size:11px; color:#000000}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<!-- List filled by people in managers team---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
Select the user on your team whose holidays you wish to view
        <select name="SelectUN" class="style4 style3">
        <option value=""></option>
        <%For cnum = 0 to Ubound(TeamMemberRows,2)%>
        <option value="<%= TeamMemberRows(1,cnum)%>"<%If Request.Form("SelectUN") = TeamMemberRows(1,cnum) Then Response.Write(" selected")%>><%= TeamMemberRows(0,cnum)%></option>
        <%Next%>
        </select>
    <br/>
<!-- List filled by people in managers team---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!-- Generates Table with holiday-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<p class="style2" style="font-weight:bold">Current Holiday entitlement for <%= strEmployee%> is <%= strEntitlement%> days</p>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="margin-top:8px">

      <tr>
        <td width="100" align="center" class="style2">Last Working Day Before Holiday</td>
        <td width="100" align="center" class="style2">First Day Back After Holiday</td>
        <td width="60"  align="center" class="style2">No. of<br />Days</td>
        <td             align="center" class="style2">Authorised By</td>
        <td width="64"  align="center" class="style2">Days Remaining</td>
      </tr>
      <%
          If strNoRecords = 0 Then
          For cnum = 0 to Ubound(HolidayRows,2)
          If HolidayRows(8,cnum) = "N" Then
            strEntitlement = CSng(strEntitlement) - CSng(HolidayRows(3,cnum))
          End If          
      %>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><%= HolidayRows(1,cnum)%><%If HolidayRows(6,cnum) = "Y" Then Response.Write(" <font color=""#5677B4"">&frac12;</font>")%></td> <!-- if half day 1-->
        <td align="center"><%= HolidayRows(2,cnum)%><%If HolidayRows(7,cnum) = "Y" Then Response.Write(" <font color=""#5677B4"">&frac12;</font>")%></td> <!-- if half day 2-->
        <td align="center"><%= HolidayRows(3,cnum)%></td>
        <td align="center"><%= HolidayRows(4,cnum)%></td>
        <td align="center"><%= strEntitlement%></td>
     </tr>
      <%Next
      End If%>
    </table>
<!-- Generates Table with holiday-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: @Diginari Have added the code to the original post.

Thanks for your help!